# Remove welcome panel from contact form 7 page

Tags: customization, plugin-contact-form-7

[image]

I'm trying to remove the welcome panel showing in the contact form page, like in the picture attached, but every code i found removing only the welcome panel in dashboard.
I want it to disappear.
Thank you

Comment: Did you click on the "Ne plus afficher" link?

Comment: "but every code i found removing only the welcome panel in dashboard" - that is the dashboard, isn't it? Where else is it appearing that you don't want it? (Did you mean never appear for other dashboard users, not just yourself?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the panel for all users, you'll need to write à little script to add user meta to the role you want.

When you click on 'ne plus afficher' an ajax script add a user meta call something like `wpcf7_hide_panel_on`, the value is an array with version where the panel will be hidden.

I think there's maybe a cookie write at the same time as even I remove the user meta, the panel still not show (I did it on local install and the cookie domain are the same...).

You need to dive in the wpcf7 code to really see what happen.